# EventBusException: its super classes have no public methods with the @Subscribe annotation

Tags: android, ros, greenrobot-eventbus, greenrobot-eventbus-3.0

I am working on the ROS android project. I am implementing the EventBus to constantly updating the value for textViews. I am posting values from ManActivity to MainFragment

But I am getting below Error

> org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBusException: Subscriber class com.korechi.roamioapp.MainActivity and its super classes have no public methods with the @Subscribe annotation

I  tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35874055/eventbus-subscriber-class-and-its-super-classes-have-no-public-methods-with-th) but it didn't help. And I am not using the proGuard so I don't think I need any rule to fix and not sure how proGuard works.

Thank you, any help much appreciated.

I am **registering** Event on **MainActivity**  and my MainActivity **extends AppCompatRosActivity**

```
  @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

**Posting** the value from **MainActivity**

```
     Subscriber<Float32> speed = connectedNode.newSubscriber("/RoamIO/speed/app_ver", Float32._TYPE);
        speed.addMessageListener(new MessageListener<Float32>() {
            @SuppressLint("StringFormatMatches")
            @Override
            public void onNewMessage(Float32 float32) {

                Log.d(TAG, "onNewMessage: /RoamIO/speed/app_ver : "+String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.speedMetric)));
                fragmentMessages.setSpeed(String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.speedMetric)));
                EventBus.getDefault().post(fragmentMessages);
//                mainFragment.speedTxtView.setText(String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.speedMetric),
//                        float32.getData()));
            }
        });
```

**subscribing** from **MainFragment** like this

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onEvent(Messages messages){
       speedTxtView.setText(messages.getSpeed());
    }
```

**Gradle**

```
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.2.0'
```

Comment: Have you @Subscribe `onEvent` in MainActivity? And Why you take this one `(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)` ?

Comment: @Ali No just in MainFragment

Comment: I am using MainThred because I need to update textView values.

Comment: And when this error comes when you go in `MainActivity`?

Comment: Yes in MainActivity

Comment: Is there `onEvent` code in your `MainActivity` ?

Comment: No just posting the Event

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219546/discussion-between-ali-and-arpit-patel).