# I have a problem receiving database data in the main thread that was dispached by EventBus from the background thread

Tags: java, android

I am learning how to retrieve data from a database through background thread and then dispatching this data to the foregrund thread for display once I have retrieved it, but my app keeps crashing with an error "MainActivity and its super classes have no public methods with the @Subscribe annotation"

I am registering the event in a Fragment that will be loaded by the MainActivity at Runtime, when the activity first comes to the screen

I tried solutions already existing here such as registering the event in onCreate() but they didn't work for me

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            param = getArguments().getString(PARAM_KEY);
        }
        //      Retrieving data from the database to display it in the RecyclerView
        db = AppDatabase.getInstance(getContext());

//      Executing database operations in a background thread
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                dataItemList = db.dataItemDao().retrieveAll();
//              Dispatching data as an event to the main thread after getting it from the database
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new DataItemsEvent(dataItemList));
            }
        });

//        Registering the EventBus
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//      Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rvItems);
        return view;
    }

    //  Receiving the event in the main thread after it has been dispatched from the background thread
    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void dataItemsEventHandler(DataItemsEvent event) {
        dataItemList = event.getItemList();

        //      Reading the settings to modify how the app displays - ( reading default preferences)
        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        boolean grid = settings.getBoolean(getString(R.string.pref_display_grid), false);

        //      instantiating the adapter
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getParentFragmentManager();
        DataItemAdapter adapter = new DataItemAdapter(getContext(), dataItemList, fragmentManager);
        if (grid) {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager((new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 3)));
        }
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
//      De-referencing the database object within the singleton as the
//      activity shuts down to avoid database leaks
        AppDatabase.destroyInstance();
//      unregistering EventBus as the activity shuts down
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have 2 questions that are why are you using EventBus? Is there any reason related to the threading problem? The second problem is you set the adapter every time you receive event is this okay?

Comment: @AbolfazlAbbasi I am using EventBus because the instructor of the LinkedIn Learning course I am watching to learn this is using it. Himself he is demonstrating in an Activity not a Fragment, but me I want to fragment my app to achieve responsiveness. But there are no threading problems. The instructor is saying it is a good practice in that it will prevent the data from blocking the UI thread incase one is dealing with large amounts of data, that it will improve operating speed of my app

Comment: try solutions suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35874055/eventbus-subscriber-class-and-its-super-classes-have-no-public-methods-with-th

Comment: @JaiprakashSoni it was one of the solutions I tried before posting my problem